# packet switching

Tags: network-protocols

I encountered this question in one of the exams that ,

> Which of the following is based on the packet switching network?
>
> (A) LAN (B) WAN (C) MAN (D) VPN

To me, it seems that all of them are packet switched. What should be the correct answer?

Comment: If this is an exam question, then should you be asking it here on SO?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) -

```
The most well-known use of packet switching is the Internet (which is basically a type of 
WAN) and local area networks (or, LAN).
```

My bet will be on LAN ( if I have to choose only one of the options ;-) )